# Saving image with Sugar ORM

Tags: android, database, orm, bitmap, sugarorm

So, I have a Bitmap image that I want to save and load. When saving it I first turn it into a byte[] value and then use save(); to save it. 
When I try to check that it worked by checking the string value of it (to check if null) I get something like this: "[B@16166c9a"
Then, I turn it back into a Bitmap value, but after doing this, the bitmap value is still null.

This is the code I use to save:

```
    public void saveImage(){
    imageToSave = Utilities.getBytes(backGround);
}
```

And this is the code I use to load:

```
    public void updateImage(){
    backGround = Utilities.getImage(imageToSave);
}
```

This is the Utilities class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class Utilities {

public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image)
{
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}

}
```

The rest of the code is available here:

https://github.com/smholsen/BigDayCountdown/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/simonm/bigdaycountdown

Sorry for messy code and bad commenting.

I very much appreciate any help! :)

Comment: First compare the byte array you are saving to the database and the one you get back from the database. If they are the same you will know the issue is not with the orm and you just narrowed down what the issue might be.

Comment: Also in most cases it's better to store the image locally and save only the file path to the database.

Comment: Allright, thanks! I will try to save it locally and save the path with ORM! Thanks for the tip mate! :)

Comment: btw, the one I got back from the db was not the one I saved to the db... Isnt that weird?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that worked form me pretty well.

```
public class ImageUtil {

public static byte[] GetByteFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

public static Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap)
{
    Bitmap bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap, 0,
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap.length);
    return bitMapImage;
}}
```